# How to disable hover css-hover-settings if element got a second class because of toggling

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add a new class to **"deactive** through the **toggling method** I want the hover settings of the "deactive class" to be ignored unless the corresponding elements have only one class in its classist.
How can I do this?

```js
window.onload = () => {
  addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.closest(".deactive").classList.toggle("active");
  });
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:30px;
}

.deactive {
  width: 30vh;
  height:10vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:50%;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color: red;
  color:black;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.deactive:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.active {
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id = "wrapper">
  <div class = "deactive">Click!</div>
  <div class = "deactive">Click!</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Instead of using 2 classes ("active" and "deactive"), just have an "active" class that is either present or not.

Comment: Or use `.deactive:hover:not(.active)` instead of `.deactive:hover`

Comment: Hi, sorry, I can not imagine what you mean properly

Comment: I do however agree with @ScottMarcus that having a button class named `deactive` isn't very descriptive. You should name it differently, like `toggle-button` or something like that.

Comment: If you keep both, make sure you remove the class not fit... You add the active class but do not remove the deactive class.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this in 1 of 2 ways.

1. Use `deactive:hover:not(.active)` instead of `.deactive:hover`.
2. Add `.active:hover { color: white; }` after the `.active` class to keep the color white instead of going back to yellow.